# How do you search amazon's api for EAN codes using the Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-web-services, barcode

I've got this:

```
  $barCode = '5055060927427';
  $amazon = new Zend_Service_Amazon($this->AMAZON_API_KEY, 'UK', $this->AMAZON_API_SECRET);
  $amazon = null;

  $amazonRes   = $amazon->itemLookup($barCode,
    array(
      'SearchIndex'   => 'All',
      'AssociateTag'  => 'NON ASSOCIATE',
      'IdType'        => 'EAN',
      'ResponseGroup' => 'Large,ItemAttributes,Images',

    )
  );
```

But this just gives me an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Service_Exception' with message '5055060927427 is not a valid value for ItemId. Please change this value and retry your request. (AWS.InvalidParameterValue)' in C:\wamp\www\easionline\src\Zend\Service\Amazon.php on line 319

The game I am trying to find is: [http://www.amazon.com/Asuras-Wrath-Playstation-3/dp/B003O6HLOK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1360139714&sr=8-1&keywords=azuras+wrath](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003O6HLOK)

Answer (score 1):

That is the normal response from the API, when the EAN doesn't exist on that locale.

You won't receive this error when you use a ean that does exist.